# Is $L$ always context free?

Tags: formal-languages

> Consider the formal language $L$ over some finite alphabet $\Sigma$ consisting of all words over $\Sigma$ that have non-trivial period (non empty prefix that is also a suffix). Is $L$ always context free?

It is a modification of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385517/is-any-formal-language-with-given-restriction-context-free). I think it's much more difficult, because it's not possible (I think) to give a counter example. Maybe pumping lemma will do?

Comment: I still want to know whether you mean words with non-trivial period or words with a non-empty prefix that is also a suffix: the two are not the same thing.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I understand your concerns. Note that the original question is not mine and this nomenclature was also surprising for me. But please let's say that in this situation non-trivial period means non empty prefix that is also a suffix as in the original question.

Comment: Sorry: I remembered the original question and didn’t check to see that it wasn’t yours. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be the pumping lemma's constant, and consider $\sigma = a^N b^N a^N b^N$. The $a$s are too far apart to be pumped together, same for the $b$s.

Answer (score 1):

If by "non-trivial period" it is meant $L = \{w^k \colon w \in \Sigma^+ \text{ and } k \ge 2\}$, the same sort of argument works for $a^N b a^N b a^N b$: Can pump at most two stretches of $a$s, if pumping a piece including a $b$ it will be too short to replicate $a^N b$.